# How do I determine the speed of a disk drive?

Tags: hard-drive, benchmark

I'm looking for a way to determine the read/write speed of a disk drive, either by looking up some system information or running a simple benchmark test utility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Xbench: Comprehensive Macintosh Benchmarking](http://www.xbench.com)

Freeware benchmarking solution for Mac OS X.

EDIT: The download link is in the right-hand corner.

Main Window
[image: Xbench startup]
Graphics Test
[image: Graphical Test]

Comment: It actually took me several minutes to find the download link on that page (top right).

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll fix it.

Comment: Oh, not your fault, I was just commenting on the page design.

Comment: Ok, It'll make it easier to find though...

Answer (score 2):

[Blackmagic Disk Speed Test](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blackmagic-disk-speed-test/id425264550?mt=12) performs various tests and tells you how fast your disk is performing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/)

I have not used it, but I plan to.

Discovered through the following article:

- [[Phoronix] Early Benchmarks Of Mac OS X 10.7 Lion](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=apple_107lion_dp1) (2011-03-02, three pages).

### Related

[OpenBenchmarking.org](http://openbenchmarking.org/) — an open, collaborative testing platform for benchmarking and performance analysis

> … an open, collaborative testing platform designed by Phoronix Media and the developers behind the Phoronix Test Suite, the most comprehensive benchmarking platform for Linux and other operating systems. …

Answer (score 0):

I'm a realist and like to see how finder does in duplicating some folders that I have data in. Documents and Music seem to give me a decent mix and you can subscribe to the apple keynote podcast to get some nice large files to test sustained reads and writes.

You can get a nice graph of the speed using Activity Monitor.